# How to calculate larger gap in array of Biginteger in C#?

Tags: c#, max, min

I got an array of random BigIntegers. Ie:

```
BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[6];
series[0]=1000;
series[1]=2000;
series[2]=4000;
series[3]=1000;
series[4]=5000;
series[5]=6000;
```

I want to find the largest gap(Ie:the larger gap is between 2001 and 3999) and return the two boundary values.

I want to know what numbers do not exist between the smallest and the largest number?

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Your question title says you want to calculate the gap (i.e. series[2] - series[1]) but your question itself says you want to achieve a larger gap. Which one is it?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: I assume that OP is a non-native speaker and meant "I want to find the largest gap and return the smallest and largest value within that gap". That would (kind of) match the example output given (2001 and 3999). That having been said, the largest gap would actually be betweeen 1000 and 5000 (at array indexes 3 and 4)...

Comment: just for clarification: you are looking for a gap of 2 items in a row ? like in a derivative ?=!

Comment: the largest gap without any occurrence which is 2001 and 3999.

Comment: "the largest gap without any occurrence" sorry, but I don't understand this. a gap that does not exist? "which is 2001 and 3999." but this is not the largest difference. look at the comment by Heinzi

Comment: I want to know what numbers do not exist between the smallest and the largest number?

Comment: ok much better now, what have you tried so far? did you program a loop and tried to calculate the differences between the numbers?

Comment: C# Math classes don't have any function for this.

Comment: Instead of array, can you use a List<int>? If so, after populating it, use a lambda expression like this: myList.Where(n=>n.value >= X && n >= Y);

Comment: "Math classes don't have any function for this. " no, you need to program it yourself. Calculate the difference of `series[i+1] - series[i]` in a for loop. then evaluate the difference and remember the index `i`

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a cycle which checks the gap and store the starting and ending indicies

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

static class Program
{
    static BigInteger abs(BigInteger i)
    { 
        return i > 0 ? i : -i;
    }
    static int Main()
    {
        BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[6];
        series[0] = 1000;
        series[1] = 2000;
        series[2] = 4000;
        series[3] = 1000;
        series[4] = 5000;
        series[5] = 6000;

        int idx1 = -1, idx2 = -1;
        BigInteger maxGap = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6 - 1; i++)
        {
            if (abs(series[i] - series[i + 1]) > maxGap)
            {
                maxGap = abs(series[i] - series[i + 1]);
                idx1 = i;
                idx2 = i + 1;
            }
        }

        if (idx1 >= 0 && idx2 >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The largest gap is between {idx1} and {idx2}");
            if (series[idx1] > series[idx2])
            {
                int swap = idx2;
                idx2 = idx1;
                idx1 = swap;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Missing values between {series[idx1]} and {series[idx2]}");
            for (BigInteger i = series[idx1] + 1; i < series[idx2]; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, BigIntHelper.GetBiggestGap will do the trick.

```
    
public static class BigIntHelper
{
    public static class BigIntHelper
    {
      public static (BigInteger start, BigInteger end) GetBiggestGap(BigInteger[] data)
      {
        BigInteger start = 0, end = 0, delta = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
          if (BigInteger.Abs(data[i] - data[i + 1]) > delta)
          {
            start = BigInteger.Min(data[i], data[i + 1]);
            end = BigInteger.Max(data[i], data[i + 1]);
            delta = end - start;
          }
        }
        return (start, end);
      }
    }
}
    
static class Program
{
    static int Main()
    {
      BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[6] { 1000, 2000, 4000, 1000, 5000, 6000 };
      var result = BigIntHelper.GetBiggestGap(series);
      Console.WriteLine($"The largest gap is between {result.start} and {result.end}");
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the question was to find the biggest Gap between any 2 items of the array, and not necessarily 2 successive one, then you just have to sort it first.
And as you know it is sorted, the remaining operations are simplified.

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Linq;

public static class BigIntHelper
{
  // find the biggest gap between any 2 elements
  public static (BigInteger start, BigInteger end) GetBiggestGap(BigInteger[] data)
  {
    BigInteger last = 0, start = 0, end = 0, delta = -1;
    foreach(var bi in data.OrderBy(bi => bi))
    {
      if (delta < 0)
        start = end = bi;
      else
        if (bi - last > delta)
        {
          start = last;
          end = bi;
          delta = end - start;
        }
      last = bi;
    }
    return (start, end);
  }
}

static class Program
{
  static int Main()
  {
    BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[6] { 1000, 2000, 4000, 1000, 5000, 6000 };
    var result = BigIntHelper.GetBiggestGap(series);
    Console.WriteLine($"The largest gap is between {result.start} and {result.end}");
    return 0;
  }
}
```